# MySQL select all entries between two dates regardless of year

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I need to find all rows in a MySQL database that fall between "YYYY-10-30" and "YYYY-12-11" I don't care about which year the the date is in just that falls between the two dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (MONTH(yourDate) = 10 AND DAYOFMONTH(yourDate) >= 30)
   OR (MONTH(yourDate) = 11)
   OR (MONTH(yourDate) = 12 AND DAYOFMONTH(yourDate) <= 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table
where
concat(year(now()),right(date_field,6))
between 
concat(year(now()),'-10-30')
and
concat(year(now()),'-12-11')
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetByMonthAndDayRange`
(
    IN monthFrom INT
  , IN dayFrom INT
  , IN monthTo INT
  , IN dayTo INT
)
BEGIN

  -- For good coding practice, name your columns instead of using *
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename
  WHERE 
     (MONTH(datecolumnname) = monthFrom AND DAYOFMONTH(datecolumnname) >= dayFrom)
  OR (MONTH(datecolumnname) > monthFrom AND      MONTH(datecolumnname) <  monthTo)
  OR (MONTH(datecolumnname) = monthTo   AND DAYOFMONTH(datecolumnname) <= dayTo);

END
```

If you use a stored procedure (and if the code works to your taste) you'll be able to code faster, just providing the parameters (it's dynamic this way)

Comment: Good idea, but with the other stuff I need in the query it didn't work.