# MySQL select row between two dates regardless of year

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns "date_from" and "date_to". When the user inputs a date i want to get the row where te picked date is between those two, however the years on those dates dont matter for me - only the months wich form something like seasons i have come to this :

```
SELECT  `date_from` ,  `date_to`
FROM  `language_courses_accommodation_periods`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(  `date_from` ,  '%c' ) <= DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  '2017-02-03',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%c' )
AND DATE_FORMAT(  `date_to` ,  '%c' ) >= DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  '2017-02-03',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%c' )
AND DATE_FORMAT(  `date_from` ,  '%e' ) <= DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  '2017-02-03',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%e' )
AND DATE_FORMAT(  `date_to` ,  '%e' ) >= DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  '2017-02-03',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%e' )
```

This works in some cases but a season can start for example at november and 
 end at march and then my query doesent return the correct result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select all entries between two dates regardless of year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198258/mysql-select-all-entries-between-two-dates-regardless-of-year)

Comment: I wonder why you have 4 conditions instead of two. The `%c`-based check will yield the same outcome as the `%e` check, or am I missing something? I mean 2017-02-01 <= 2017-02-01 will yield true, just like 2017-02-28 <= 2017-02-028, no?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Try this query it might work by splitting the days from the months you are creating too many possibilities for the answer to be.

```
    SELECT  `date_from` ,  `date_to`
    FROM  `language_courses_accommodation_periods`
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(  `date_from` ,  '%c-%d' ) <= DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  '2017-02-03',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%c-%d' )
    AND DATE_FORMAT(  `date_to` ,  '%c-%d' ) >= DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  '2017-02-03',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%c-%d' )
```

Comment: I did try that but in some cases there may not be an existing season for the picked date. Then the query will return a wrong result based on the `OR` condition.
Example :
date_from:2016-07-03;
date_to:2016-08-14;
searched date:2016-05-04

Comment: Did you try the one I posted? I depends how you wrap the brackets eg. They will produce different results. You should also try joining the the month and day together because that date should show as it fits between 03 and 14 so one of the conditions are met. Ill update my answer with another suggestion you can try

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN`, which doesn't care about the order of the arguments at the right:

```sql
SELECT  `date_from`, `date_to`
FROM    `language_courses_accommodation_periods`
WHERE   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2017-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d'), '%c')
            BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(`date_from`, '%c')
                AND DATE_FORMAT(`date_to`,   '%c')
```

I don't think there is any additional value in repeating this condition with the `%e` format.